# Read and write to JSON on x10Hosting

Tags: json, angular

I have an angular 2 project, how can I read and write to a JSON file on my server?

I can do what I want within my code itself bit I don't want to have to change my code, recompile and upload my website every time.

Any help? Examples are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Angular can read the remote JSON file using the [HTTP Client](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) but it can't directly write to the remote file.

For writing, you can use a server side script such as PHP (supported by x10Hosting) to provide a url that allows Angular to post to (also using the HTTP Client), to update the JSON.

For example something like this PHP:

```
$data = json_decode('./data.json'); // decode the json
$data->something = $_POST['something']; // update the something property
file_put_contents('./data.json', json_encode($data)); // write back to data.json
```

Comment: how would i talk to the script in my app then?

Comment: would I do something like `this.http.post('/script.php', body)` and pass the json in the body?